# ElasticSearch-Camel component connect to remote cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel

I'm trying to connect to an elastic search cluster on a different subnet. I've tried connecting using the cluster name, node names and the ip

```
elasticsearch://aaclust?ip=10.10.1.11&port=9300&operation=INDEX&indexName=statistics&indexType=customer_statistic
```

The cluster has 2 nodes aaclustes1(10.10.1.11) and aaclustes2(10.10.1.12) and the cluster name is aaclust. I'm using camel 2.15.1 and the same version of elastic search component

Any tips would be appreciated I'm new to Elastic Search.

Comment: Try using transportAddresses instead.

Comment: as far as I can see transportAddresses works only on 2.16 that is not released yet http://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html